# dijit.layout.ContentPane shifts right on page load

Tags: dojo, dijit.form, dijit.layout

I have a problem which I am unable to fix, maybe somebody can help?

I have a dijit.layout.ContentPane at the top of my page, this sits in a dijit.layout.BorderContainer. On page load the contents of the container shift right and down by about 15px. All other elements work fine.

I have isolated the issue to dijit.layout.ContentPane. In side the container I am running some php if statements and drawing some simple buttons:

```
<!-- Here are the common buttons above the tabs -->

<div id="toolPane" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top" >

    <?php 
    if($this->restrict == 1){
        if($this->teammembers == 1 || $this->newleaders == 1 || $this->newadminleaders == 1){ 
            if ($this->mayUpdateSummary){
    ?><span style="white-space:nowrap;" ><?php echo $this->issueActionLink($issue, 'Create report', 'report', 'reportLink'); ?></span>
    <span style="white-space:nowrap;" ><a class="emailLink" href="mailto:?subject=Task%20%23<?php echo $issue->id; ?>&body=<?php echo urlencode($this->serverUrl(true)); ?>">Share link</a></span><?php
    }
    }
    }else if($this->restrict == 2){
        if ($this->mayUpdateSummary){
    ?><span style="white-space:nowrap;" ><?php echo $this->issueActionLink($issue, 'Create report', 'report', 'reportLink'); ?></span>
    <span style="white-space:nowrap;" ><a class="emailLink" href="mailto:?subject=Task%20%23<?php echo $issue->id; ?>&body=<?php echo urlencode($this->serverUrl(true)); ?>">Share link</a></span><?php
    }
    }
    ?>

<?php if ($this->mayUpdateSummary): ?>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;" ><?php echo $this->issueActionLink($issue,'Edit summary', 'progress-summary', 'editbutton'); ?></span> 
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($closeButton): ?>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;" ><?php echo $closeButton; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($reopenButton): ?>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;" ><?php echo $reopenButton; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle where we can see the problem ?

Comment: I think the php part won''t work on jsfiddle, @ccoles3 could you please create the jsfiddle but with your static HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we have decided to hide the page until the dijit elements have loaded. To do this we have added this script which fades in the page giving it time to sort itself out before it is displayed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".content").hide();
     });

    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".content").fadeIn("fast");
     });
</script>

<div class="content">
[faded in content goes here]
</div>
```